# How to split all combinations of two lists N times cleaner?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Pardon if the question is titled confusingly. I couldn't think of a better way to word it. Anyway, I have a Python program that accepts a list of first names and a list of last names. It then "splits" the two into all of their combinations, with a maximum of 5 results. The code explains it better:

```python
def getLists(firstNames, lastNames, resultCount):
    firstNameCount = len(firstNames)
    lastNameCount = len(lastNames)

    if firstNameCount >= resultCount:
        # Return the last name list as is.
        return [firstNames[i * firstNameCount / resultCount:(i + 1) * firstNameCount / resultCount] for i in xrange(resultCount)], [lastNames for _ in xrange(resultCount)]

    else:
        lastNameLists = []
        firstNameLists = [[firstNames[i % firstNameCount]] for i in xrange(resultCount)]

        for i in xrange(resultCount):
            firstName = firstNameLists[i]
            total = firstNameLists.count(firstName)
            already = total - firstNameLists[i:].count(firstName)
            lastNameLists.append(lastNames[already * lastNameCount / total:(already + 1) * lastNameCount / total])

        # Return the last names, split depending on how many results and first names.
        return firstNameLists, lastNameLists
```

If there are less first names than the maximum (5), the first names are repeated until the maximum and the last names are distributed among the first names:

```python
firstNames = ['firstName{}'.format(i) for i in xrange(1, 3)]
lastNames = ['lastName{}'.format(i) for i in xrange(1, 8)]
comboCount = len(firstNames) * len(lastNames)
resultCount = min(comboCount, 5)
firstNameLists, lastNameLists = getLists(firstNames, lastNames, resultCount)

for i in xrange(resultCount):
    print 'Result #{}:\nFirst Names: {}\nLast Names: {}'.format(i + 1, firstNameLists[i], lastNameLists[i])
    print
```

Output:

```
Result #1:
First Names: ['firstName1']
Last Names: ['lastName1', 'lastName2']

Result #2:
First Names: ['firstName2']
Last Names: ['lastName1', 'lastName2', 'lastName3']

Result #3:
First Names: ['firstName1']
Last Names: ['lastName3', 'lastName4']

Result #4:
First Names: ['firstName2']
Last Names: ['lastName4', 'lastName5', 'lastName6', 'lastName7']

Result #5:
First Names: ['firstName1']
Last Names: ['lastName5', 'lastName6', 'lastName7']
```

If there are more first names than the maximum (5), the first names are distributed as evenly as possible and the last names are copied for each:

```python
firstNames = ['firstName{}'.format(i) for i in xrange(1, 8)]
lastNames = ['lastName{}'.format(i) for i in xrange(1, 8)]
comboCount = len(firstNames) * len(lastNames)
resultCount = min(comboCount, 5)
firstNameLists, lastNameLists = getLists(firstNames, lastNames, resultCount)

for i in xrange(resultCount):
    print 'Result #{}:\nFirst Names: {}\nLast Names: {}'.format(i + 1, firstNameLists[i], lastNameLists[i])
    print
```

Output:

```
Result #1:
First Names: ['firstName1']
Last Names: ['lastName1', 'lastName2', 'lastName3', 'lastName4', 'lastName5', 'lastName6', 'lastName7']

Result #2:
First Names: ['firstName2']
Last Names: ['lastName1', 'lastName2', 'lastName3', 'lastName4', 'lastName5', 'lastName6', 'lastName7']

Result #3:
First Names: ['firstName3', 'firstName4']
Last Names: ['lastName1', 'lastName2', 'lastName3', 'lastName4', 'lastName5', 'lastName6', 'lastName7']

Result #4:
First Names: ['firstName5']
Last Names: ['lastName1', 'lastName2', 'lastName3', 'lastName4', 'lastName5', 'lastName6', 'lastName7']

Result #5:
First Names: ['firstName6', 'firstName7']
Last Names: ['lastName1', 'lastName2', 'lastName3', 'lastName4', 'lastName5', 'lastName6', 'lastName7']
```

How could I make `getLists` more efficient, readable, and/or cleaner?

Comment: Look at `itertools` module and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements

Comment: Use product in itertools, I wonder why you wanna generate names, actually you can use https://github.com/joke2k/faker faker to fake names as you wish.

Comment: ```itertools``` doesn't seem to have anything I see that solves the problem described in the question.

Comment: It does have all you need, it obviously requires some effort to exclude those results you don't need.

Comment: I don't see any functions in ```itertools``` that would make this code any more efficient, readable, and/or cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The demo is Python3, if you use Python2, try to make a little code change if possible:

```
firstNames = ['firstName{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 3)]
lastNames = ['lastName{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 2)]

from itertools import product, islice

print(list(islice(product(firstNames, lastNames), 5)))
```

the islice ensure it returns the first 5 result, if the results is less than 5, it's still OK.

Comment: Try to use random or sample if you want your results to be evenly distributed.